# Crontab not executing my python script every 5 minutes

Tags: python, cron

I know a lot of people ask the same but I can't see my fail.

My goal is execute a code every 5 minutes and this is my cron line,

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/myUserName/folder-name-path/main.py
```

I did all what I know and find,

- The first line of the script has `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- If I execute my script without cron doesn't crash.
- I did `which python3` and says "/usr/bin/python3".

Can somebody explain me where I'm mistaking?

**EDIT:**

Following what @CherryDT has said, I must add that the structure of my project is similar to:

```
folder-name-path
   |-> lib (folder)  -> Some python scripts
   |-> data (folder) -> Some CSV data
   |-> temp (folder) -> A json file.
```

And inside my scripts I import the python files as `from lib import foo`.

**EDIT2:**

Ok the problem is not my cron script, the problem is the subfolders inside my main folder.

I tried scheduling another script without imports and works well. Then I'm practically sure the problem is with the imports. Can somebody say me what can I can I do? I tried starting with

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

But I have an error, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`

I tried

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

And I obtain the main path, `/home/myUserName/folder-name-path`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Start by logging the output and check what you see in the log afterwards: append `2>&1 >/home/myUserName/log.txt`

Comment: My gut tells me that your script expects to be run with its working directory set to the directory where the script is located, perhaps because you are using relative paths in the script, and it doesn't work properly because the working directory is something else when run from cron. You could try adding `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` at the start of your script.

Comment: @CherryDT mmm in fact, `folder-name-path` has the main.py file but it import some other scripts that  `folder-name-path/lib`  and some json files inside ` folder-name-path/data`, this is not correct?

Comment: Another note: #!/usr/bin/python is only needed if you are making your python script an executable and calling it standalone (e.g. /somepath/main.py). Since you are executing it as argument to python interpreter, that line is not required.

Comment: Did you try the two suggestions? And insightful log output? Any difference with the chdir command in place?

Comment: I did the second one because the first one I'm not sure how to do it and I'm reading some posts to write it well. It's like this? `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/myUserName/folder-name-path/main.py 2>&1 >/home/myUserName/log.txt`

Comment: With the second one appears this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''` I'm really sorry I know I'm asking to much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was with the paths inside my code. **Crontab needs the absolute paths.**

As I see it doesn't has problems to arrive to the user, but if then you have different subfolders in your main folder it will crash.

What I did to solve it, is obtain the main path, `cwd`,

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

And define all paths adding `cwd` at the beggining, for example in my case:

```
csv_data = cwd + '/folder-name-path/data/myData.csv'
json_data = cwd + '/folder-name-path/temp/myTemp.json'
```

Also I added `__init__.py` in my `lib` folder not sure if it was necessary but it helps to python to understand this folder has scripts.

Thanks!!